# Sojourner Badge explained?

Tags: ingress

I'm pretty unsure how this thing works, is it that I need to hack *the same* portal for x days, or do I need to hack *any* portal for x days?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Niantic have confirmed this for us.

> You may hack any Portal - it does not have to be the same Portal every time.

[image: Niantic sojourner clarification]

Answer (score 8):

It seems it's *any* portal.

I'm at 10 days at the moment, and on weekends I'm not following my usual daily routine, meaning I'm only walking to a closer portal not en route to work. Still counting.

Answer (score 1):

## Max 36 hours, any portal, only successful hacks count

**NOTE: These "rules" are not officially supported and may change at any time!**

**The only rule that is *confirmed* by Niantic is "max 24 hours per hack", although they have admitted there is a little bit of grace, but they never confirmed what that grace is.**

I just did some testing on this, and the rules appears to be as follows:

- You gain Sojourner medals for achieving a Hack Steak of 15, 30, 60, 180 and 360 days
- Hacking on any portal counts
- Only successful hacks count; failures due to full inventory does not count
- Max 36 hours between hacks to maintain the Hack Streak

So this is the series of hacks I did, and the corresponding Hack Streak counter

- Sunday, 20:12, 0 days
- Monday
- Tuesday, 08:10, 1 day
- Wednesday, 20:08, 2 days
- Thursday
- Friday, 08:06, 4 days
- Saturday, 20:04, 5 days
- Sunday
- Monday, 08:02, 7 days
- Tuesday, 19:00, mistaken **failed** hack (inventory was full), 7 days (should have been 8)
- Tuesday, 20:04, successful hack, 0 days

It might be worth noting that the Hack Streak counter said 8 days in the seconds just before the Tuesday 20:04 hack, and was then 0 directly after.

### Notes on the Hack Streak counter

- The Hack Streak counter is unreliable. It can say the Hack Streak is still on when it has in fact been reset
- The time of day of the very first hack *only* tells when the hack streak counter will tick over after on a successful hack
- The tick-over time is UTC, so if you started at 13:00 standard time, it will tick over on 14:00 in daylight saving time
- The counter may tick over despite you *not* having hacked for that period, so you cannot use that as an indicator to recall if you have hacked successfully recently or not